# Save result of for loop in a vector

Tags: r

I think I'm just too tired to see the mistake. I wrote a function to get the maximal value for two data sets from a 'for' loop:

```
plot_zu <- function(x) {for (i in 1:x){
    z=data_raw[grep(a[i], data_raw$Gene.names),]
    b=data_raw_ace[grep(a[i], data_raw_ace$Gene.names),]
    p<-vector("numeric", length(1:length(a)))
    p[i]<-max(z$t_test_diff)
    return(p)} 
}
```

Imagine: a is a vector of names and the data set `(data_raw(_ace))` is filtered by it. In the end, I would like to have all maxima values of column `t_test_diff` in a vector. After that I want to add the `t_test_diff` column values from data_raw_ace also.

So the problem is, that I get this:

```
[1] 1.210213 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
[8] 0.000000 0.000000
```

So there is a problem with brackets or something but I cannot see it ( first value fits). Sorry for no good example but i think it is understandable and an easy to solve question.

If need be, I can add another example.

Thanks a lot!!

gratefully,

Hendrik

Comment: Move `p<-vector("numeric", length(1:length(a)))` to before your `for (i in 1:x)` and put `return(p)` outside of your first `}`?

Comment: @mrdwab yeah that works, thx. is there a function to get the most negative / positive value without changing + or -? :)

Comment: I'm guessing you want to get the `max( abs( ...))` value?

Comment: @DWin   na because then it returns me only positive values. Since its about ratios (Protein expression) i need to extract pos and min maximas .. sry. and thx!  picture: (same gene name:  ratios : -2 , 1 -> return -2 . ; )

Comment: The function to use on two vectors for what I think you want is `apply(cbind(a,b), 1, function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of data and even the call you make to this function, I'm going to offer an alternative based on what I think you are attempting. It appears you want to select only those rows of "data_raw" whose "Gene.names" column values are in the set defined by "a". If so, that is just:

```
 z <- data_raw[ data_raw$Gene.names %in% a , ]  # no loop needed

 b <- data_raw_ace[ data_raw_ace$Gene.names %in% a , ] # again no loop needed
 # Next step is unclear
```

If you want to use grep or grepl inside "[" then use sapply:

```
 z <- data_raw[ sapply(a, grep, x= data_raw$Gene.names), ]  # (still) no loop needed
 b <- data_raw_ace[ sapply(a, grep, x= data_raw_ace$Gene.names),  ]
```

When you do this, what is it that is desired?

```
p<-vector("numeric", length(1:length(a)))
p[i]<-max(z$t_test_diff)
```

If you want the maximum value for an identically named column in the two subset of data, then do this:

```
p <- pmax( z$t_test_diff, b$t_test_diff )
```

Based on you further comments above I (now) think maybe:

```
p <- apply( cbind(z$t_test_diff), abs(b$t_test_diff), 1, function(x) x[which.max(abs(x))])
```

Comment: nice, but the reason why i used the grep function is, that it appears that in the column Gene.name some entries are like this: App1;App2 so with the %in% thing i do not get these rows, right?

Comment: See further suggestion. Still unclear what the task is after subsetting is done.

Comment: nice one, one more issue: by using b <- data_raw_ace[ sapply(a, grep, x= data_raw_ace$Gene.names),  ] i get an arrow massage; Fehler in `[.default`(xj, i) : ungültiger Indextyp 'list' but i checked the sapply function and it works, it seems like i have to change the class but why?

Answer (score 0):

`vapply` does this, eliminating the `for` loop.  Not tested.

```
vapply(1:x, FUN.VALUE=numeric(1), FUN=function(x) {
    z=data_raw[grep(a[i], data_raw$Gene.names),]
    b=data_raw_ace[grep(a[i], data_raw_ace$Gene.names),]  # Is this needed?

    return(max(z$t_test_diff))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are overwriting p in each new iteration by defining it inside the loop.